# Let $F$ be a field. Find all prime and maximal ideals of $F[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field. Find all prime and maximal ideals of $F[x]$.

I have no idea on how to start this question. I try to use the theorem that '$F[x]/I$ is a field $\Leftrightarrow$ $I$ is a maximal ideal $\Rightarrow$ I is a prime ideal'. But I realised that $F[x]/I$ is not unique, that is different $I$ may yield different field.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Realizing that the quotient is a field iff the ideal is prime is a good start. But you should look closer at why this is the case. The reason is that ideals of this ring have a very special form, which should help you determine what the prime ideals look like.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the fact that $F[x]$ is a PID and that prime elements and irreducible elements in this ring coincide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that for any ring $R$,
$$R/I\text{ is a field} \iff I \text{ is maximal}\implies I\text{ is prime}.$$
It is not in general true that
$$I\text{ is maximal}\impliedby I\text{ is prime}.$$
The corresponding characterization of prime ideals is
$$R/I\text{ is a domain}\iff I\text{ is prime}.$$

**Hint for the problem:** The ring $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain. That is,

- every ideal of $F[x]$ is principal; in other words, for any ideal $I$, there is an $f$ such that
  $$I=(f)=\{f\cdot g\mid g\in F[x]\}.$$
- $F[x]$ is a domain; in other words, if neither of $f,g\in F[x]$ are the zero polynomial, then $fg\neq 0$.

Now characterize when $I$ is prime in terms of properties of how $f$ factors (remember, every polynomial in $F[x]$ factors into irreducibles). In any ring every maximal ideal is prime, but the converse is not true. In the case of $F[x]$, there will be exactly one prime ideal that is not maximal. Here is a hint for what it is: *the ring $F[x]$ is not a field*.

Comment: How do we know $F[x]$ is a PID ?

Comment: @Idonknow: $F[x]$ is a [Euclidean domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) because $F$ is a field (degree argument), and this implies PID.

Comment: @Idonknow: I assume (and hope!) it was proven in your class, or in a section of your textbook that you covered, prior to this question being asked...